# Variable is changed when I add "\n" in println

Tags: java, floating-point, char

I am a new Java student and struggling to understand what error occurs for the following code to output 11.7 instead of 1.7 . Why does the code change when I use the char version and why does it add a 1 specifically?

```
public class FloatVersusDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // FLOAT VS DOUBLE
        float num =1.7f;
        System.out.println(num + '\n');     
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Variable is changed when I add "\n" in println

You're not adding `"\n"`, you're adding `'\n'`. The former is a `String`, the latter is a `char`.

The meaning of `+` depends on the [types of the operands](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18):

- When you use `+` with a `float` and a `String`, you're doing *string concatenation*, since at least one of the operands is a `String`;
- When you use `+` with a `float` and a `char`, you're doing *numeric addition*, since both of the operands have numeric types.

With numeric addition, the two operands undergo [*binary numeric promotion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6), to make them compatible for adding. Since the "widest" of the two operands is a `float`, the `char` undergoes promotion to a `float`. Since the codepoint value of `\n` is 10, the float value is `10.f`. Then, the two floats are added together, giving you `11.7f`, which is printed as `11.7`.

If you want to print `num` followed by a newline (followed by another newline, since you're using `System.out.println`), change `'\n'` to `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

In java the primitive type `char` is considered as a number when combined with numeric operators.
What are you doing with the code

```
num + '\n'
```

is the equivalent of the pseudocode

```
num + valueAsIntegerOf('\n')
```

and `\n` is the ascii value 10, so you are doing

```
num + 10
```

If you would like to print the number and two new lines (one is added by the method println you can do it in different ways:

```
// First solution add a second println
System.out.println(num);
System.out.println();

// Second solution convert num to a string and add \n to that string
System.out.println(String.valueOf(num) + '\n');

// Same as the second solution but using the automatic conversion to 
// string caused by "\n"
System.out.println(num + "\n");
```

The simplest way is to use the third solution. This work because you are trying to combine with the operator + a number and a string. In this case the number is changed to a string and it is combined with the \n